# Amazon S3 access policy for a typical web application with RBAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization, access-control, rbac

Evaluating S3 for storage needs of a node.js web application with `Role Based Access Control (RBAC)`.

There are two scenarios for accessing S3:

*Scenario 1:* An authenticated user logs in to our application. The application allows the user to perform CRUD operations to resources (which are part of the users' profile) persisted on S3.

*Scenario 2:* Any user can access (read-only, of course) other user's public profile (which will contain resources served from S3). The concept is not unlike linkedin or other applications where a user's public profile may be visible to 'all' users.

This is what I tried:

1. Created two groups, `GROUP_RW` with `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `GROUP_R` with `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess`
2. Created users under both these groups
3. For 'Scenario 1' access S3 as `GROUP_RW` user
4. For 'Scenario 2' access S3 as `GROUP_R` user

However, under `Bucket | Permissions | Grantee`, I do not see the users created for `GROUP_RW` and `GROUP_R`.

How would one go about enforcing this kind of a policy?